# PHP Looping arrays and inner array data

Tags: php, arrays

Having a little issue with getting the barcode and sku from this example array

```
{
  "title": "This is the title",
  "variants": [{
    "barcode": "123456789", 
    "sku": "sku1"
  }]
}
```

PHP

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

     $products[] = Array(
        "title" => $product["title"], // product title
        "barcode" => $product["variants"]["barcode"], // product barcode
        "sku" => $product["variants"]["sku"] // product SKU
     );
  }
```

Comment: Have you decoded your json properly?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: Yea its all valid, thats just an example data i just wrote on here as far to much data to paste but need to get the sub data of the array

Comment: You're assigning the new values to the same `$products` array. I am almost sure it was not intentional

Comment: Well first on turn on error reporting and check if you get some errors or warnings: `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` Also take a look at the structure of your array with `print_r($products);` to see what you got in there. Right now you just show us an array, where you would loop over `title` and `variants`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data looks like JSON, so you'll need to convert it to a PHP array first:

```
$products = json_decode($data, true);
```

Now you can iterate like this:

```
$product_array = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {

    $product_array[] = array(
       "title" => $product["title"], // product title
       "barcode" => $product["variants"][0]["barcode"], // product barcode
       "sku" => $product["variants"][0]["sku"] // product SKU
    );
}
```

Notice the added `[0]` in the `foreach` loop, as well as the `$product_array` array (because you were overwriting the `$products` array in the loop itself). The `[0]` is to get the first element of the array `variants`, as there can be more. You could add another `foreach` loop to iterate them all.

Also note that you already have a complete array after using `json_decode`. You can check that by just running:

```
var_dump(json_decode($data, true));
```

Where `$data` contains the JSON data you mentioned.

**Updated answer with loop inside loop:**

```
$product_array = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    // I'm using the name $item, if I used $product it would overwrite the variable in the loop
    $item = array(
        "title" => $product["title"], // product title
        "variants" => array() // for now an empty array, we will fill it in the next step
    );

    // now we fill the empty arrays inside the array above, by iterating all variants
    foreach($product["variants"] as $variant) {
        $item["variants"][] = array(
            "barcode" => $variant["barcode"], // product barcode
            "sku" => $variant["sku"] // product SKU
        );
    }
    $product_array[] = $item; // now we add the item with all the variants to the array with all the products
}

var_dump($product_array); // show the results
```

Comment: Im a little new to PHP, could you maybe give me an example so did not have to use [0] and using another loop? although that did work and displayed my data fine... if there is a better way would like to learn the better way of course :) and i already json the data from PHP framework i think... well i assume as when loaded page was loading all fine.

Comment: Sure thing, added it to my answer!

Answer (score 5):

Try this hope this should work:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {

     $products[] = Array(
        "title" => $product["title"], // product title
        "barcode" => $product["variants"][0]["barcode"], // product barcode
        "sku" => $product["variants"][0]["sku"] // product SKU
     );
  }
```

Comment: Yep that done the trick, i was going to try [0] but thought would just do the first  but it does loop as expected thanks mate

Comment: I went to accept but could not for 10 minutes but just have done that :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$a = '{
"title": "This is the title",
"variants": [{
  "barcode": "123456789", 
  "sku": "sku1"
 }]
}';
$products = json_decode($a, TRUE);
$products = Array(
   "title" => $products['title'], // product title
   "barcode" => $products['variants'][0]["barcode"], // product barcode
   "sku" => $products['variants'][0]["sku"] // product SKU
);
```